# oath2 (fusionauth) in Django-Rest-Framework and React

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, fusionauth

I am sure there is something I fundamentally do not understand about oath2.

I am trying to make **django-rest-framework** and **react** work w/ **fusionauth**.

In react I have a button that redirects to the fusionauth authentication page.  Once a user successfully logs into fusionauth, it sends a code to a redirect URL on the django backend.  That DRF view exchanges the code for an authentication token and some other other info like an ID.  Using that ID, I can find a corresponding (local) django user and generate a JWT token (or whatever sort of authentication system I wind up using) for that user and return it as JSON.

The bit I don't understand, is how do I pass that JSON back to the frontend?

Comment: Do you mean "how do I use the JSON from FusionAuth in the Django views" or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Not quite.  I mean: How do I pass the JSON I retrieve from FusionAuth (via the redirect URL in the Django views) to React.

Comment: How would you pass any other data from django to react?

Answer (score 0):

I did eventually get this working.  My solution was to make the redirect URL from FusionAuth goto the *frontend*.  Once the frontend is passed an authorization code (just a URL Parameter in the GET), then it passed that code to the backend using a standard fetch.  The backend returned w/ tokens and user details.  Once those got stored in state, the frontend knew the user was authenticated.